# Filtering localized content (Sanity / groq / typescript (Document Internationalization)

Tags: next.js13, sanity, groq

Could somebody please help me out with the following? Have a data set ('legal') in Sanity which contains a document-specific language field ('en'/'nl' etc (string 'language')). This is part of the [document-internationalization plug-in](https://github.com/sanity-io/document-internationalization/tree/main) and will be applied within NextJS13.

I have made a groq-specific rendering in Sanity selecting the legal documents. The document requiring further filtering to only display those documents that ar applicable to the current language.

groq-query:

```
export const legalJPSlugsQuery2 = groq`*[_type == "legal" && defined(language) && defined(slug.current)]{
  language,
  title,
  "slug": slug.current,
}`
```

loader.ts:

```
  export const getLegalsJPWithSlugs = (preview = false) => 
  cachedClientFetch(preview)(legalJPSlugsQuery2, COMMON_PARAMS)
```

layout.tsx:

```
import {COMMON_PARAMS, getLegalsJPWithSlugs} from '@/sanity/lib/loaders'
import FooterLinks from '@/components/FooterLinks';

export default async function RootLayout(props) {
  const queryParams = {...COMMON_PARAMS, language: props.params.language}
  const legals = await getLegalsJPWithSlugs(queryParams)

  const children = (
    <>
      {props.children}
      <FooterLinks legals={legals} />
    </>
  )

  return (
    <html lang={props.params.language}>
      <head>
*etc...*
```

footerlinks.tsx:

```
'use client'

import Link from 'next/link'
import React from 'react'
import {SanityDocument, Slug} from 'sanity'
import {clean} from './Clean'
import { useParams } from 'next/navigation'
import { getLegalsJPWithSlugs } from '@/sanity/lib/loaders'

type FooterLinksProps = {
  // language: string
  language: string
  legals: any[]
  }

export default function FooterLinks(props: FooterLinksProps) {
  const {legals = []} = props
  const {language} = useParams()
 
  return legals?.length ? (
    <footer className="container mx-auto p-4 md:p-8 xl:p-16 flex flex-col md:flex-row md:flex-wrap justify-end gap-4 align-middle">
      {legals.map((legal) =>   //requires additional filtering to only display current language'
        legal?.slug? (
          <Link
            key={legal._id}
            href={`/legal/${legal.slug}`}
            className="text-cyan-500 hover:text-pink-500 font-medium text-sm"
          >
            {legal.title}
          </Link>
        ) : (
          <span key={legal._id} className="text-gray-500 font-medium text-sm">
            {legal.title}
          </span>
        )
      )}
    </footer>
  ) : null
}
```

I am struggling how to apply such filtering - tried to apply language === [$language] replacing 'defined(language)' in groq but that results in errors whilst '(language == 'en')' runs without any problems) so trust that this is effectuated by the truescript components.

Would be extremely grateful receiving some guidance from any of you coding-heroes.